# For a new project using Spring with JDBCTemplates, iBatis/myBatis or Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring, persistence, ibatis, mybatis

Hi there we are starting a project in which we have to make the decision between using Spring JDBCTemplates, iBatis/myBatis or Hibernate for our persistence layer. I am more or less familiar with the concepts from both of them but i am wondering what people currently tend to use.

My requirements are:

- keep everything as simple as possible
- easy learn and use
- high performance
- optimal developer productivity
- must be usable with Spring 3

As noted we would like to keep everything as simple as possible. My preference tends to lean toward iBatis/myBatis because it looks easier to use and we do not need a real OR Mapper. But i am really looking forward to learn from the guys that use these frameworks.

Comment: Is there a presentation layer? I only ask because if you don't need a presentation layer then ORM might take a back seat to JDBCTemplates.

Comment: No there is no real presentation layer, we are building a webservice layer.

Comment: Are there a lot of business rules that need to be applied?

Comment: The goal is to put the business logic in the service layer, project is rather small. But needs to be very stable and performant, the webservice layer will be used a lot by other systems.

Answer (score 5):

I've worked with Ibatis and Hibernate. Ibatis is straightforward and simple. Hibernate can get complicated if you're not careful, but it does a lot for you. spring-jdbc is better than raw JDBC.

Hibernate's biggest advantage is being able to map to different databases. You can even turn off schema prefixes. You have options like using an in-memory database for testing, or having developers use local databases different from the production target (for instance if you're targeting Oracle and licenses are a problem), or being able to target multiple databases. Swapping out id generators is easy with Hibernate. With Hibernate native SQL is an option, but with Ibatis there is no choice.

Also it is hard to impossible to keep the Ibatis mapping files DRY. If you have multiple queries with different where clauses, cut-n-paste will result. With Hibernate there is nowhere near as much duplication.

Both Ibatis and Hibernate have a declarative caching mechanism, by the way. Hibernate's is much more involved, of course.

spring-jdbc shares all the disadvantages I've listed for Ibatis. In addition I don't think it has a caching mechanism. its main benefit is that the JDBC objects are not as well-hidden, so you can get direct access to them more easily if you need it.

Spring integrates with all three alternatives, spring support is not a differentiator.

One more thing: Hibernate works great with artificial keys. It can manage composite business keys but it's much more work. Ibatis and spring-jdbc are not sophisticated enough for this issue to matter for them.

If your developers are cautious and thorough, and if you can keep your approach simple (for instance, using session-per-request, not retaining any objects from one session to the next, and using artificial keys), then go with Hibernate. If you've decided you don't need the database abstraction that Hibernate provides, or you don't trust your developers with sharp tools, then go with Ibatis. Keep spring-jdbc in mind as a fall-back to do particular queries that need bare-metal jdbc tweaking.

By the way, Grails and GORM make Hibernate much easier to experiment with because there's so much less setup time, Grails starts you out with an in-memory database and you can get by without writing mapping files.

Answer (score 5):

I advise you to have a look at [minuteproject](http://minuteproject.sf.net) reverse-engineering solution for spring/hibernate/ibatis and also JPA(2), since it fulfill your development requirement. There is one thing that it does not generate (yet) is jdbctemplate.

Before opting for a technology, I will review all your points that fit in the minuteproject approach.

- **keep everything as simple as possible**: Let minuteproject generates for you the code you need for persisting in iBatis (sqlMaps), in Hibernate (hbm files), in JPA (orm file or annotated entities). But all the additional framework integration: spring configuration, a comprehensive DAO stack (not limited to basic CRUD ops). It can correspond from 20 to 40% of your Application artifacts and time.
- **easy learn and use**: your model becomes your technology tutorial! Learn from what has been generated. You can of course extend it for your specific need.
- **high performance**: in the minuteproject track for Spring/hibernate or Spring/JPA: minuteproject provides ehcache configuration generation integrated with orm product.
  It provides and avanced dao layer with tuned query that you just have to reference.
- **optimal developer productivity**: It helps you focusing on your real business and not all the tedious orm / dao tasks. It flattens the technology learning curve.
- **must be usable with Spring 3**: The spring artifacts are comptible with 2.5+

But the best one that can judge is you, so try it on you model. To have a quick overview of the possibility start /bin/start-console.(cmd/sh), point to your database and chose a generation track. It should normally take a few minutes if your database is (mysql, db2, oracle, hsqldb have default value such as hibernatedialect preset).
To go more advance use the configuration (it is for all db).

Regarding to which technology to use, personally I have production experience with all of them, but I would consider that the bidirectional aspect of orm frameworks such as hibernate is a strong point over unidirectional sqlmap. It saves configuration and graph navigation is intuitive.

A goody: Escaping special character such as ', is including in orm frameworks. And this is a problem you would commonly face while performing native sql in sqlmap such an insert of a lastname = 'o'hara'...

I would go for Hibernate (among the choice you mention), but go for [JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2) (if you would have included it). If you want real extra productivity integrate [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) for compilable criteria API in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate offers you nice and easy way to map native SQL queries in addition to ORM while iBatis offers only SQL mapping. So with Hibernate you have more options and can use ORM or native SQL when needed. For that reason I prefer Hibernate.

Hibernate definitelly integrates well with Spring. iBatis probably does as well but I never used such integration.

These are my two cents. If someone has different opinion, please post another answer.

Comment: Understood. That's why +1 for your question. I can only share my experience and would be happy if someone comes up with more detailed comparison. On the other hand, it may be very hard to put the balance between complexity of framework and simplicity of the use case. If it's only 1 or 2 simple queries and no chance of evolving, JDBC may be just fine, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

For these two objectives:
- keep everything as simple as possible
- easy learn and use

Both MyBatis and JdbcTemplate will work fine. Both them just provide a high level API to access your database with SQL.

You will save code with MyBatis because it will be able to do most of the mappings (from result sets to objects) and you will save objects if you use mappers (dynamic interfaces that map methods to sql statements).

On the other side you will probably get the best performance with JdbcTemplate because hand coded mappings are faster than introspection.

Regarding "optimal developer productivity". Hibernate is more productive than MyBatis/JdbcTemplate but it requires more skills and experience otherwise your productivity can go really low.

All them are really well integrated with Spring 3

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no presentation layer and it sounds like the majority of the business rules will be out side of the persistence layer my suggestion would be Spring's JDBCTemplate.  While I have used ibatis before my experiences with Hibernate and Spring far exceed my experiences with ibatis so I provide the following reasons for my suggestion.

**Hibernate**
-While hibernate is an excellent framework for persistence **it takes someone with experience to get the most out of hibernate**.  Some developers treat hibernate as a black box and they get careless with their HQL and cause massive performance issues.  Since your looking for an easy to pick up and understand persistence layer - I would avoid this.  **But**, if you don't use hibernate you **loose out on** the simple **caching** system that hibernate provides out of the box.  Not having a caching system at your figure tips stinks so I would consider integrating one in any other solution where performance is important.

**Spring**
-Spring's JDBCTemplates should be pretty easy for most anyone to understand.  It's not a new technology or framework and Spring's goal is to just make things easier to use.  Since one of your requirements is the Spring3 I would assume that most of you team is already familiar with the idea of dependency injection, row mappers, and DTOs?  Whatever solution you pick I would also take advantage of **Spring's transactional testing tools**.  Lastly, debugging performance issues with JDBCTemplates are a lot easier than with hibernate.

**iBatis**
-Since my experience with iBatis is little I would only suggest this over JDBCTemplates if your team has had positive experience with this tool.  It is a somewhat less popular solution to the other two but it does seem like a nice middle ground.